# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)

Tags: java, json

I've been getting this error. How can I fix it?

#### Error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input 
>   at Function.parse [as parseJSON] () 
>   at Object. (:128:24) 
>   at i (jquery.min.js:2) 
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2) 
>   at A (jquery.min.js:4) 
>   at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4QoO.png) (transcribed here)

#### File *asqBatch.jsp*

When I click the button.

```
function genExcelRep() {
    var param = "${urlExcelLink}?year=${batchData.year}&period=${batchData.period}&programId=${batchData.programId}&batchId=${batchData.batchId}";
    repDialog = BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: "Generating Report",
        message: '<h1 style="text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:40px;color:black"></i>&nbsp;5%</h1>',
        onshow: function(dialogRef) {
            dialogRef.enableButtons(false);
            dialogRef.setClosable(false);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  param,
                cache: false
                })
                .done(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                    alert(json.pid);
                    alert("done(function(result) 1");
                    dialogRef.setMessage(data.result);
                    alert("done(function(result) 2");
                    if(data.isSuccess) {
                        alert("if(data.isSuccess)");
                        if(data.result == "Session Timeout") {
                            alert("Session Timeout");
                            SessionTimeOutRedirect("${redirectLink}");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("generateExcelReport jsp");
                            generateExcelReport(data);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("else(data.isSuccess)");
                        dialogRef.enableButtons(true);
                        dialogRef.setClosable(true);
                    }
               });
        },
        closable: false,
        closeByBackdrop: false,
        closeByKeyboard: false,
        buttons: [{
            label: 'Close',
            action: function(dialogRef) {
                dialogRef.close();
            }
        }]
    });
 }
```

#### Controller

```
    model.addAttribute("urlExcelLink", "mainASQBatch/DownloadExcel.htm");
    model.addAttribute("contGenExcelUrl", "mainASQBatch/contGenerateExcel.htm");
```

#### The @RequestMapping part

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/DownloadExcel") //
public void DownloadExcel(@ModelAttribute("ResultASQDataVO") ResultASQBatchVO vo, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse res) {
    logger.info("generateExcelReportPart1 year:" + vo.getYear() +
                "," + vo.getPeriod() +
                "," + vo.getProgramId() +
                "," + vo.getBatchId());
    ResultASQDataVO rec = new ResultASQDataVO(vo.getYear(),
                                              vo.getPeriod(),
                                              vo.getProgramId(),
                                              vo.getBatchId());

    if(CommonMethod.IsSessionTimeOut(session)) {
        rec.setResult("Session Timeout");
        rec.setSuccess(true);
    }
    else {
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        String result = "";

        try {
            logger.info("generateExcelReportPart1 1");
            List<ResultASQDataVO> lstReport = resultASQDataSER.distinctWorkSheet(
                new ResultASQDataVO(rec.getYear(),
                                    rec.getPeriod(),
                                    rec.getProgramId(),
                                    rec.getBatchId()));

            String arr = lstReport.toString();
            rec.setListReports(String.join(";", arr));
            logger.info("generateExcelReportPart1 2");
            int cnt = lstReport.size() + 1;
            String dirReports = ReportCommonMethod.getTempReportFolderWithTimeStamp(new File(context.getRealPath("/")));
            rec.setDirPath(dirReports);
            rec.setFiles("");
            float noIncrement = 0f;
            rec.setSuccess(isSuccess);
            logger.info("generateExcelReportPart1 3");
            if(CommonMethod.validate(rec.getListReports())) {
                rec.setSuccess(true);
                noIncrement = 100/(cnt);
                logger.info("generateExcelReportPart1 4");
                while(noIncrement*cnt>100) {
                    noIncrement -= 0.25;
                }
                isSuccess = true;
                result = REPORT_GENERATE_RESULT.PROGRESS.getAlert(String.valueOf(Math.round(noIncrement)) + "%");
            }
            logger.info("generateExcelReportPart1 5");
            rec.setCurrentProgress(noIncrement);
            rec.setNoIncrement(noIncrement);
            rec.setResult(result);
            rec.setSuccess(isSuccess);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info("Localized Message: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            logger.info("Exception Message: " + e.getMessage());
            logger.info("Exception Cause: " + e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The *values* in "rec.setResult(result)" should be shown in the module .jsp file.

Comment: In your screenshot, console.log(result);  var data = $.parseJSON(result); showing null, you need to see the response from server.

Comment: how to see the response of the server?

I tried log it and it shows values. 

logger.info("rec.setResult(result);"+rec.getResult()+"rec.setSuccess(isSuccess);"+rec.isSuccess());



ResultASQBatchController - rec.setResult(result);<h1 style='text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin' style='font-size:40px;color:black'></i>&nbsp;1%</h1>rec.setSuccess(isSuccess);true